# JSON import generates run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, type-mismatch

I receive run-time error '13' Type mismatch when trying to import some data via IEX API using JSON.

I receive the error when setting the values for the cells in the For Each loop.

Here's a link to view the API data: 
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual

```
Sub getFinancials()

'Write to ws
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Financials")

Dim ticker As String
ticker = ws.Range("P7").value

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Clear Range
ws.Range("A1:L" & lastrow).Clear

'Array Column Headers
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("reportDate", "grossProfit", "costOfRevenue", "operatingRevenue", "totalRevenue", "operatingIncome", "netIncome", "researchAndDevelopment", "operatingExpense", "currentAssets", "totalAssets", "totalLiabilities", "currentCash", "currentDebt", "totalCash", "totalDebt", "shareholderEquity", "cashChange", "cashFlow", "operatingGainsLosses")
Arrsize = UBound(myarray) - LBound(myarray) + 1

Dim rngTarget As Range
Set rngTarget = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Arrsize + 1, 1))
rngTarget.value = Application.Transpose(myarray)    

'Send web request for API Data
u = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" & ticker & "/financialsperiod=annual"
' https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual
Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myrequest.Open "Get", u
myrequest.Send

'Parse JSON
Dim JSON As Object
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)

'Get # of Objects in Array
Dim arrayLen As Integer
arrayLen = JSON.Count

'Loop through Elements
Dim element As Variant
Dim x, y, r As Integer
r = 2
y = 2
x = 1

While x < arrayLen + 1
    For Each element In myarray
        ws.Cells(r, y).value = JSON(2)(element)
        y = y + 1
    Next element

    y = 2
    x = x + 1
    r = r + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that JSON(2)(element) should be JSON(x)(element).

Comment: H A Kapadia. Welcome to stackoverflow!. For your information: `Dim x, y, r As Integer` will give you `x As Object`, `y As Object` and `r As Integer`. What you need to type is `Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, r As Integer`

Comment: @Ahmad, actually x and y will be Variant. And although it's better to declare x and y as Integer explicitly, this declaration will not prevent it from working if everything else is correct

Comment: JsonConverter.ParseJson can return a Collection or a Dictionary, (so your arrayLen Variabel is already confusing). Try using the watch window to see how your data is structured. The twin braces in JSON(2)(element) also look wrong....

If 'JSON' is a dictionary you are trying to write whatever is in 'element' to the key "2" (as integer/long), although it expects a String.

What data are you expecting from the JSON Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran the JSON through the converter and this is the structure that I get:

- -Dictionary(2 items)
- --Collection(4 items)
- ---Dictionary(20 items)

You need to extract the data accordingly. Collections can be looped through with a simple for each loop. Dictionarys can be looped through with the following structure.

```
Option Explicit


Sub PrintFinancialReports()

    Dim apiURL As String
    apiURL = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual"

    Dim myrequest As WinHttpRequest
    Set myrequest = New WinHttpRequest

    myrequest.Open "Get", apiURL
    myrequest.Send

    Debug.Print myrequest.ResponseText ' print received JSON to check if it is valid

    Dim FinancialReportQuery As Dictionary
    Set FinancialReportQuery = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)

    Debug.Print FinancialReportQuery.Item("symbol")

    Dim Reports As Collection
    Set Reports = FinancialReportQuery.Item("financials")

    Dim report As Dictionary
    For Each report In Reports
        Dim reportContentKey As Variant '<-- variant is needed to loop a dictionary
        For Each reportContentKey In report
            Debug.Print reportContentKey, report.Item(reportContentKey)
        Next reportContentKey
    Next report

End Sub
```

Hope this helps